# MySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a mysql server in a docker container and connect it with a phpmyadmin container.

phpmyadmin works just fine, but cannot connect to the DB. Examining the status of the DB container shows: "Restarting". I tried different images following their online demos but none worked.

Digging into docker logs, I found this error:

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 206:    67 Killed                  "$@" --daemonize --skip-networking --socket="$SOCKET"
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
        - mysql:db
    ports:
        - 8000:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        PMA_HOST: db
```

From the logged error, was thinking it's missing a SOCKET environment variable, added it to the docker-compose file, but didn't help. I tried with `docker run`, faced the same issue with an 'Exited' status of the container.

This is persistent regardless of the image I use for the container (mysql/mariadb).

Note: Docker is installed in a vagrant VM.

I can't get my hands on the issue causing the problem. Was thinking digging into the [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) script and tweaking. Any ideas what might be the source of this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the old docker containers to get mariadb to work. However, mysql still hangs in the middle of the process of setting up the container.

Will work with maridadb and perhpas check mysql later.